# Where is the post featured image link stored in the WordPress database?

Tags: wordpress

Where is the featured image link stored in the WordPress Database?  I searched in the `wp_postmeta` table but I cannot find out the exact `post_id` and `links`.

Is this correct? Could anyone please explain to me how it works?

Comment: how and  where they are linking both `post_id` and image ?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

The featured image ID is stored in `wp_postmeta` with a `meta_key` called `_thumbnail_id`. Example:

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════╗
║ meta_id ║ post_id ║ meta_key      ║ meta_value║
╠═════════╬═════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 200     ║ 4       ║ _thumbnail_id ║ 48        ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

The actual thumbnail link is then contained in `wp_posts` with a `post_type` of `attachment`. Example:

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ post_type  ║ guid                                                ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 48 ║ attachment ║ http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/yourimage.png ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: I know this is old, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for a clear and correct answer!

Comment: VERY helpful.  I exported these tables directly from the database using PHPmyAdmin SQL structure and data/drop table/complete inserts. Ran a find and replace on the doman name in the resulting SQL file. Then ran the SQL in a new wordpress DB.   It was the only thing that restored the featured images correctly during the migration.

Comment: To anyone trying to create these relationships artificially, there seems to also be a requirement of a second postmeta record for the thumbnail post with key `_wp_attached_file` and value = attached file path (i.e., `/2020/10/...`) for it to appear using the `get_post_thumbnail()` function. It's possible I messed something else up along the way, but that's what worked for me.

Comment: Thanks so much. exported a site without featured images. this helped to restore the attachments using phpmyadmin

Answer (score 15):

I was curious, so here goes...

- The `wp_postmeta` table will hold an entry for the post with `meta_key` of `_thumbnail_id`
- the `meta_value` is a child `post_id` for the featured image
- using that `post_id`, you can obtain further information from `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`

To put it all together, here's how to get the child `wp_posts` row for the featured image of post `XXX`...

```
SELECT childpost.* 
FROM wp_posts childpost 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta parentmeta ON (childpost.ID=parentmeta.meta_value)
WHERE parentmeta.meta_key='_thumbnail_id' 
AND parentmeta.post_id=XXX;
```

And here's the meta data for that same image

```
SELECT childmeta.* 
FROM wp_postmeta childmeta 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta parentmeta ON (childmeta.post_id=parentmeta.meta_value)
WHERE parentmeta.meta_key='_thumbnail_id' 
AND parentmeta.post_id=XXX;
```

The metadata will include a `_wp_attached_file` relative path, and a `_wp_attachment_metadata` containing some PHP serialized data.

Comment: What would be the SQL where I could get the image that wordpress compresses, I mean the other sizes: 300x300, 150x150 (wordpress sizes per image) ?

Answer (score 15):

here my sql with full url image

```
SELECT concat((select option_value from wp_options where option_name ='siteurl'  limit 1),'/wp-content/uploads/',childmeta.meta_value)
FROM wp_postmeta childmeta 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta parentmeta ON (childmeta.post_id=parentmeta.meta_value)
WHERE parentmeta.meta_key='_thumbnail_id' and childmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
AND parentmeta.post_id = POST_ID ;

select option_name from wp_options where option_name ='siteurl'
```

the result will be like this

> `http://yourdomain/blog-wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/IMG_06062014_155904.png`

Comment: Saved me time as I was juat about to write the same thing. #thx

Comment: It answers the question by providing not only the actual fields and tables where the value is stored, but provided the esoteric SQL statement needed to access the value.  +1  The question that should have been asked is "What version of Wordpress does this apply to?"  Because for version 4.8 (and probably an unknown number of prior versions), the above answers as nice as they are, are no longer valid.  Things change.

Comment: This works fine on WP 6.1.1

Answer (score 11):

Even if [rnevius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28643825/) answer seemed correct, the result returned some images with this kind of URL :
http://www.example.com/?attachment_id=48 which was not working in my case.

**Tested on Wordpress 4.9.3 :**

Another solution is to use `_wp_attached_file` instead :

**wp_postmeta**

Search for value `_thumbnail_id` in `meta_key`

```
meta_id   | post_id   | meta_key            | meta_value
200       | 4         | _thumbnail_id       | 48
```

**wp_postmeta**

Again in `wp_postmeta`, search for value `_wp_attached_file` in `meta_key` where `post_id` is matching the `meta_value` find in previous query

```
meta_id   | post_id   | meta_key            | meta_value
1020      | 48        | _wp_attached_file   | 2018/09/picture.jpg
```

Query :

```
SELECT wp.ID, wpm2.meta_value
FROM wp_posts wp
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wpm
        ON (wp.ID = wpm.post_id AND wpm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wpm2
        ON (wpm.meta_value = wpm2.post_id AND wpm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file')
```