# extract the path of all the featured images of my articles

Tags: wordpress, image

I should extract the complete path of all featured images of all my articles.
Can they be found in the database?
Can I get them somehow?
I need the URL of featured images and understand which article is connected

I would need something like this for all the articles:
title ----> url of the featured image

Thank you all

Comment: You have two ways. 1. Wordpress way: query all post, loop and store their featured image in an array using `get_the_post_thumbnail()` or `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`. 2. A manual SQL query to retrieve all `meta_value`from all `_thumbnail_id` `meta_key`, this will contain ID of post of type `attachment` that you can then query [see or structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643654/where-is-the-post-featured-image-link-stored-in-the-wordpress-database)

Comment: thanks for your kind response. I am not able either with the first nor with the second.
could you help me?

Comment: select 
avwp_postmeta.meta_value
,avwp_posts.ID 
,avwp_posts.guid 
,avwp_posts.post_type
,avwp_posts.post_title 
from avwp_postmeta 
left join avwp_posts on avwp_postmeta.meta_value = avwp_posts.ID 
where avwp_postmeta.meta_key='_thumbnail_id'
I tried this but I do not get what I'm looking for

Comment: please post the code you've tried so we can help @Riccardo

Comment: Did my answer worked? I haven't tested the code but it should. If not, please post errors or unexpected behaviors. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this as said in my comment :

1: Query all posts

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'post',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

2: Loop on all posts and store thumbnail URL

```
$thumbs_urls = [];
foreach($the_query->posts as $post){
        $thumbs_urls[$post->ID] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post);
}
```

3: `$thumbs_urls` should give you something like this (where array key is the post ID)

```
[
    1 => 'https://post_1_thumb_url.jpg',
    2 => 'https://post_2_thumb_url.jpg'
]
```

Not tested but should work.

Note: if you have a very large amount of posts, and depending on your PHP configuration, a timeout could occur. If this append, you can use `post_per_page` and `page` query parameters to limit the execution time and do it "step by step".